# Jenkins with Assembla

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm struggling with Jenkins to work with a git repo on Assembla.

I made a SSH keys using windows command lines, then went to my Assembla account to setup the public key in it. Afterwards I created new credentials into Jenkins and set the private key to it.

I also added to the git configuration in Jenkins the same email user and name user as my git configuration in windows.

Then when I create a new job and I set my assembla git url with thoses credentials, I do not have an error telling me that access is denied like the feedback when not using the right credentials. But still, when I manually launch a build, I have this log:

```
Building in workspace C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential Assembla
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@git.assembla.com:test.git
 > D:\Logiciels\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@git.assembla.com:test.git
 > D:\Logiciels\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.26.2.windows.1'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > D:\Logiciels\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@git.assembla.com:test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "D:\Logiciels\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@git.assembla.com:test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: cannot spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test@tmp\jenkins-gitclient-ssh335926776093448729.bat: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2639)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2079)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:601)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:830)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1223)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1301)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1204)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:636)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:508)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm fairly new to Jenkins and followed this video as a tutorial thinking that git hub and assembla would be alike: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdIG0af7S0g&ab_channel=GameFeelings

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the issue, it seems Jenkins doesn't work well with an family licence on Windows. I'm currently building with the same setup on a pro licence.